# Visual studio 2014 deployment error

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssas, ssms, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to run my very first dimension with visual studio 2014 and it's not really going smooth.. I did all checks I could (change it to specific window account authentication, check data sourced and provider, make sure that sql server is running ...) but it's still not working... I'm a beginner and the error messages do not make much sense to me yet.

Below is the details I got when I tried to deploy my dimension.

---------------Details------------------------------------

```
<Batch xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
  <Parallel>
    <Process xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ddl2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2" xmlns:ddl2_2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2/2" xmlns:ddl100_100="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2008/engine/100/100" xmlns:ddl200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200" xmlns:ddl200_200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200/200" xmlns:ddl300="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300" xmlns:ddl300_300="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300/300" xmlns:ddl400="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2012/engine/400" xmlns:ddl400_400="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2012/engine/400/400">
      <Object>
        <DatabaseID>MVA_SSAS</DatabaseID>
        <DimensionID>Date</DimensionID>
      </Object>
      <Type>ProcessFull</Type>
      <WriteBackTableCreation>UseExisting</WriteBackTableCreation>
    </Process>
  </Parallel>
</Batch>
    Processing Dimension 'Date' completed.
        Start time: 22/06/2016 00:26:05; End time: 22/06/2016 00:26:05; Duration: 0:00:00
        Processing Dimension Attribute '(All)' completed.
            Start time: 22/06/2016 00:26:05; End time: 22/06/2016 00:26:05; Duration: 0:00:00
        Processing Dimension Attribute 'Month Number Of Year' completed.
            Start time: 22/06/2016 00:26:05; End time: 22/06/2016 00:26:05; Duration: 0:00:00
Errors and Warnings from Response
    Internal error: The operation terminated unsuccessfully.
    The following system error occurred:  There are currently no logon servers available to service the logon request. 
    Errors in the high-level relational engine. A connection could not be made to the data source with the DataSourceID of 'Adventure Works DW2014', Name of 'Adventure Works DW2014'.
    Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while the dimension, with the ID of 'Date', Name of 'Date' was being processed.
    Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while the 'Month Number Of Year' attribute of the 'Date' dimension from the 'MVA_SSAS' database was being processed.
    Server: The current operation was cancelled because another operation in the transaction failed.
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. The problem was that I didn't have any pw to my windows...Thought that it might be useful if someone gets the similar error. :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should worry about this:

```
A connection could not be made to the data source with the DataSourceID of 'Adventure Works DW2014', Name of 'Adventure Works DW2014'.
```

Test that data connection again. Check the impersonation account, save password if needed...

Comment: Thank you @vercelli but I did check impersonation account and everything there is correct. (same as the one at management studio). I did test connection through connection manager and it gives me a feedback that connection is correct.....